# FEDEX Shipping Rate API Error Msg: 'Account number not found.'

Tags: php, fedex

Has anyone encountered this error message recently while using FEDEX's shipping rate API??

I've been working with the FEDEX shipping rate API for ~a week now, and my code `(run [this][1] which requires [this][2] and [this][3])` was working smoothly until today.  I made very few changes, which I did not track (unfortunately).  All of the auth/account info is TEST info provided by FEDEX.  Now I see the following error, code of which is not described on FEDEX's [error codes page][4]:

```
Severity: ERROR
Source: crs
Code: 850
Message: Account number not found. 
LocalizedMessage: Account number not found.
```

Upon searching, it looks like there's no talk of this error on the web. It's not authentication related, because upon messing with the key/meter/password info, I get another error related to authentication.  So it's authenticating just fine, but doesn't see my account number.  The request XML verifies that there is an account number where it should be, so it appears that this message is related to "finding" the account number in FEDEX's database.

I thought maybe there was an issue with my account, so I created another account, replaced the info, and sure enough, same error message is getting returned.

**UPDATE** Code:

- http://pastie.org/pastes/4229615
- http://pastie.org/4229610
- http://pastie.org/4229624
- [Fedex.com - Appendix O: Error Codes](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/product/WebServices/MyWebHelp_August2010/Content/Proprietary_Developer_Guide/Error_Codes_conditionalized.htm)

Comment: We're going to need to see some code.

Comment: Thanks for looking, Alex! Edited my post to include a few pasties...I hope that helps.

Comment: The same thing happened to me. I called Fedex yesterday and they said their whole testing service is down. They have no ETA on when it will be back up. Looks like it is still down as of this morning....

Comment: A simple text search on the [Fedex](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/product/WebServices/MyWebHelp_August2010/Content/Proprietary_Developer_Guide/Error_Codes_conditionalized.htm) link you provided yields: `Special service conflict. Return Shipment Voice Call Tag is not valid with Home Delivery Premium Appointment.`

Comment: @Davinder - I wonder if they recently added those codes?? I certainly did multiple ctrl+F's looking for that error code...Either way, I believe that code is irrelevant to the operation I'm performing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if($var == 'shipaccount') Return 'XXXXXXXXX';  -->Test Account Number
if($var == 'billaccount') Return 'XXXXXXXXX';  -->Test Account Number

    if($var == 'meter') Return 'XYXYXYXYXY';  -->meter number
if($var == 'key') Return 'XYXYXYXYXYXYX'; --->key
if($var == 'password') Return 'FOOFOOOFOO'; -->password
```

Hope you have filled these fields correctly.
I have also noticed today that fedex shipping rates are not returning whereas it was working fine until last week, so there may be changes with fedex. You have to contact fedex regarding this.
Also make sure you have downloaded and included RateService_v10.wsdl file.

Comment: Well, at least I can't blame my coding! Thanks everyone for your answers, I hope FEDEX clears this up soon.